# Cannot find module './students.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

Tags: angular

I'm facing these issues in angular 12 version, I'm unable to connect the JSON file

Comment: What issues? Please add them to the body of your question.

Comment: Should this be tagged [angular] instead of [angularjs] since it isn't AnglarJS 1.x related?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Place the below setting into compilerOptions of tsconfig.json. See the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, even with this in both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.vite.json`, using Vite.

Answer (score 2):

create a file named "json-typings.d.ts" in your app directory and paste the code below.

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).